# How to not minimize the particular windows on Show Desktop?

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, stickynotes

I use Indicator Stickynotes 0.4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity installed on it.

After all windows minimizing with a Show Desktop icon or Ctrl + Super + D shortcut, notes are going with them too.

I've looked in the unity-tweak-tool, ccsm for an option to not minimize particular windows after switching to desktop and did not find anything.

Are there some ways to stick my notes and don't let them disappear whenever i want to check them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ccsm->general->general setting-> Hide skip taskbar info(3rd from top). Uncheck it. That is what is use in case of gkrellm.

Comment: Wasn't aware of ccsm existence, thanks for this and for the solution.